# How to edit text between tags with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to capture number range and replace it with the numbers, but only within a specific tag.

```
$str = "This is some (the numbers are between 8, 9-12) and we have some 9-12 outside";
```

The output should be

```
$str = "This is some (the numbers are between 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) and we have some 9-12 outside";
```

I need to capture only `9-12`, which is between parenthesis, and only replace it not `9-12` outside parenthesis.

Comment: You can't do this with only regex. You could create a function to extract the interval value transform it in a list of numbers then replace the interval.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I handled the first part, but how to limit the replace to the substring within the parenthesis only?

Comment: `\(.*?([\d]+-[\d]+)\)` and you get only the first group: https://regex101.com/r/lZ1tM5/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this with `preg_replace_callback` and a `\G` based pattern:

```
$str='This is some (the numbers are between 8, 9-12) and we have some 9-12 outside';

echo preg_replace_callback('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\()[^)0-9]*+(?:[0-9]++(?!-[0-9])[^)0-9]*)*+\K([0-9]++)-([0-9]+)~', function ($m) {
    return implode(', ', range($m[1], $m[2]));
}, $str);
```

Pattern details:

```
~
(?:  # two possible beginnings
    \G(?!\A)  # position after the previous match
  |           # OR
    \(        # an opening parenthesis
)
[^)0-9]*+ # all that is not a closing parenthesis or a digit 
(?:
    [0-9]++ (?!-[0-9]) # digits not followed by an hyphen and a digit
    [^)0-9]*
)*+
\K  # the match result starts here
([0-9]++) # group 1
-
([0-9]+)  # group 2
~
```

If you want to limit the number of steps to obtain a match, you can rewrite the beginning of the pattern: `(?:\G(?!\A)|\()` like this: `\G(?:(?!\A)|[^(]*\()`. In this way, the pattern will no more fail until an opening parenthesis but will quickly reach it avoiding (limiting) the cost of a (most of the time) failing alternation at the start of the pattern.

Comment: This is magically wonderful! I cannot believe its powerlessness. I doubt if there could be a better answer!

Comment: @All: Thanks, but a pattern can often be improved (in particular when you have additional informations about the string). To well understand what happens take the time to see how `\G` patterns are designed *(there are many examples in SO)*, how and why they work *(to be or not to be contiguous)*. Once done, in a second time, you can search about possessive quantifiers that are only here to improve the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('#\([^\)]+\)#', $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $m) {
    $str = str_replace($m, str_replace('-', ', ', $m), $str);
}
```